# Finding parents of item with class

Tags: jquery

looking for some more helping targettingting elements based on finding others.

So I have markup as below - and when a page is open the `<li>` with class “sidebar-page” has “sidebarItemOpen” added - so Body link 1 below is the active page. What I want is to be able to add the class “sidebar-pages-open” to the parent `<div class=“sidebar-pages”>` element and also add the class “caretOpen” to the parent `<span class=“caret”>` element.

I don’t seem to be able to locate the parents of the `<li>` with the class “sidebarItemOpen” to make it work on page load though… any tips?

I need to loop through each version of the "sidebar-pages" div to locate the "sidebarItemOpen" class (there will only ever be one li with the "sidebarItemOpen" class).

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sidebar-section').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".sidebar-pages li.sidebar-page").hasClass("sidebarItemOpen")) {
      $(this).closest('.sidebar-pages').addClass("sidebar-pages-open");
      $(this).closest('.caret').addClass("caretOpen");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="sidebar-section">
  <a href="link1">Link 1</a>
  <span class="caret"></span>

  <div class="sidebar-pages">
    <ul>


      <li class="sidebar-page sidebarItemOpen">
        <a href="bodylink1">Body link 1</a>
      </li>

      <li class="sidebar-page">
        <a href="bodylink2">Body link 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>



<li class="sidebar-section">
  <a href="link2">Link 2</a>
  <span class="caret"></span>

  <div class="sidebar-pages">
    <ul>


      <li class="sidebar-page sidebarItemOpen">
        <a href="bodylink3">Body link 3</a>
      </li>

      <li class="sidebar-page">
        <a href="bodylink4">Body link 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: `$("li.sideBarItemOpen").parent()`

Comment: Please also include the javascript that you wrote that is not working

Comment: You have two elements with that class, so there are two parents.

Comment: The DIV is not the parent. The parent is the LI. Maybe what you want is `.closest("div.sidebar-pages")`?

Comment: @Taplar - just added - have a look and let me know

Comment: `$(this).closest('.sidebar-pages')` <= `this` there is still the section.  The pages are not parents of the section.  They are children.  You need to do a find there as well, just like you did for the if statement

Comment: OK. got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - got it working as below:

```
$(function() {
$('.sidebar-section').each(function(){
if ($(this).find(".sidebar-pages li.sidebar-page").hasClass("sidebarItemOpen")) {
    $(this).children('.sidebar-pages').addClass("sidebar-pages-open");
    $(this).children('.caret').addClass("caretOpen");
 }
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `if`, `$(this)` is the current `.sidebar-section` element in the iteration. `.closest()` is then looking for ancestor elements of that, but the elements you want to find are descendants.

You can set a variable to the `.sidebarItemOpen` element, and then navigate relative to that. There's no need for `.hasClass()`, just include `.sidebarItemOpen` in the selector.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sidebar-section').each(function() {
    let openItem = $(this).find(".sidebar-pages li.sidebar-page.sidebarItemOpen");
    openItem.closest('.sidebar-pages').addClass("sidebar-pages-open")
                                      .siblings('.caret').addClass("caretOpen");
  });
});
```

```css
.sidebar-pages-open {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.caretOpen {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="sidebar-section">
    <a href="link1">Link 1</a>
    <span class="caret"></span>

    <div class="sidebar-pages">
      <ul>
        <li class="sidebar-page sidebarItemOpen">
          <a href="bodylink1">Body link 1</a>
        </li>

        <li class="sidebar-page">
          <a href="bodylink2">Body link 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="sidebar-section">
    <a href="link2">Link 2</a>
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <div class="sidebar-pages">
      <ul>
        <li class="sidebar-page sidebarItemOpen">
          <a href="bodylink3">Body link 3</a>
        </li>

        <li class="sidebar-page">
          <a href="bodylink4">Body link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```